# Is there any way to read a fragmented file from the Harddisk without moving it's clusters?

Tags: windows, winapi, storage, ioctl, fileapi

I have been writing a program to read the contents of a file directly from the Harddisk. I have been mostly successful with non-fragmented files, using the FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS, I get the location of the file on the harddisk and then using SetFilePointerEx, i start reading the file directly from the harddisk. Since the file is not fragmented, I read the harddisk till the file size.

for example:
if the file size is 120345 bytes, I read 120345 bytes from the hard disk.

The problem arises when the file is fragmented, now I know where each fragment of the file starts, but I don't know till where each fragment ends, I was hoping to read only the individual fragments and concatenate the resultant data to get my output. The problem becomes multi-fold if the volume is a spanned volume since I would have to deal with multiple hard disks as well.

Are there any APIs or IOCTLs that could be used in synchronous to tackle this problem?

Comment: Why are you doing it this way?  Why not just read the file through the regular file read mechanism?

Comment: Me and my friends are working on a project where we are encrypting a file in such a way that the data of the file is encrypted when kept on the harddisk. The file gets decrypted when the user opens the file. So the only way to view the encrypted data is by directly reading it from the harddisk using the above method.

Comment: No, it isn't the only way. You can add a read hook.

Comment: I am using the ReadFile function from fileapi.h to read the data, I'll have to do some learning for implementing the read hook approach.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using [BitLocker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/data-protection/bitlocker/) or another full-disk encryption solution?

Comment: The major reason for this project is to get low level experience in windows drivers and kernels. We started this project when we were working with cloud and thought let's implement something like this. No specific reason for not using Bitlocker but just wanted to try and implement something ourselves and possibly customize it further.

Comment: Well to read a file off the hard disk directly you need to use the directory entry to tell you where all its pieces are. In other words you need to use all the data in `FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS`, not just the first item.

Comment: *I don't know till where each fragment ends* - [`FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-retrieval_pointers_buffer) - ***NextVcn** 
The VCN at which the next extent begins. This value minus either **StartingVcn** (for the first Extents array member) or the **NextVcn** of the previous member of the array (for all other Extents array members) is the length, in clusters, of the current extent*

Comment: I have observed for my file, the RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER's extent count is 1 and the array has only 1 value which tells us that the file resides on a single extent. However, the NextVcn still has a value and it is not 0, which it should if there is no "Next VCN". Moreover I used another tool called WinHex which allows me to open the entire harddisk and search through it and I observed that the data of the file is actually fragmented. I am really confused with these mixed signals.

Comment: This only mean your code is wrong

Comment: How would that be considering the RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER is returned by windows ? The buffer is receive has a single extent but the extent itself has a valid NextVcn.

Comment: Show us your code and someone may show you your error. Don't show it and nobody can.

Comment: @kshitijSabale - *The buffer is receive has a single extent* - of course no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved the issue. Somehow my Extents array is still showing a single extent but to get all of the fragmented data I had to call `FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS` multiple times.

If I call this function:

```
DeviceIoControl(handle,
                FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS,
                &StartingVCNK,
                sizeof(STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER),
                prpb,
                sizeof(RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER),
                &nRead,
                NULL);
```

it would return `ERROR_MORE_DATA` if the file was fragmented and there are more extents. So I had to call `DeviceIoControl()` until it returned `ERROR_HANDLE_EOF`. Also I had to update `StartingVCNK` to the `NextVCN` of the previous extent.

Comment: `sizeof(RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER)` this is logical mistake. you can and must allocate much lager buffer. such code not efficient